# Get multiple email adresses from a textarea

Tags: php, post, foreach, textarea

I have a question: i need to create a POST method form with a textarea, where the user can copy-paste multiple email adressses and my form should be able to do something with each adress separately.
And i don't know how to tell to php to recognize each email adress separately from the POST value of the textarea and insert them into a table of my database for example.

so my code looks like that for the moment:

```
<?php

if($_POST) {

   if(!empty($_POST['emails'])) {

      $emails = explode(" ", $_POST['Emails']);

      foreach($emails as $email) {

            /* Do something with each adresses ( like inserting them into a 
             table in my database for example) */

      }

   }

}

?>
<html>
   <form class="mx-auto" method="POST" id="invitations">
       <div class="form-group w-50 mx-auto text-center">
           <label for="emails">Insert the email adresses</label>
           <textarea name="emails" id="emails"></textarea>
           <button id="send-data" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto my-5 text-center">Send the invitations</button>
       </div>
   </form>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to split the values in the textarea on something, are the email addresses seperated with a newline or character you could simply explode it. 
There also is a possiblity tht you could use regexp group capture but I would not recommend it if you could avoid it.

Comment: I think i just solved the problem alone, i used the explode function so when a user insert multiple email adresses separated with one space each adresse get's treated by the form. And i just added the function (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) into my foreach and that do the job :) i will edit my post with the good code and mark it as solved

Comment: What if your user uses commas or newlines to separate them? Your form doesn't instruct them in any way.

Comment: I added the new code below

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST['Emails'])) {
    
    $emails = explode(" ", $_POST['Emails']);
    
    foreach($emails as $email) {

        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {


            // Do something

        } else {

            echo "This email adress is not valid => $email !";
            return;

         /* here if something else than a space or a valid email adress is inserted 
            the foreach will be exited and a error message specifying where
            something was wrong is displayed :) */

        }
    }

} else {

    $feedback = "Please insert one or multiple email adress(es)";

}

if(isset($feedback) and !empty($feedback)) {

    echo $feedback;

}

?>

<html>
   <form class="mx-auto" method="POST" id="invitations">
        <div class="form-group w-50 mx-auto text-center">
            <label for="emails">Insert the email adresses</label>
            <small>Separate them with a space</small>
            <textarea name="emails" id="emails"></textarea>
            <button id="send-data" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto my-5 text-center">Send the invitations</button>
       </div>
   </form>
</html>
```